# What does `act` and `cat` mean in ActivityManager in Android?

Tags: android

When I capture `adb logcat` in an Android application. I see below log:

```
ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE]
```

I don't understand what `act and cat` mean in the above log. Does them relate to ActivityManager? I couldn't find any clue in the doc.

Comment: act stands for Action and cat stands for Category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`act` means action, and `cat` means category.

Here's a snippet of what `Intent.toString` does:

```
public void toShortString(StringBuilder b, boolean secure, boolean comp, boolean extras,
        boolean clip) {
    boolean first = true;
    if (mAction != null) {
        b.append("act=").append(mAction); // Action
        first = false;
    }
    if (mCategories != null) {
        if (!first) {
            b.append(' ');
        }
        first = false;
        b.append("cat=["); // Categories
        for (int i=0; i<mCategories.size(); i++) {
            if (i > 0) b.append(',');
            b.append(mCategories.valueAt(i));
        }
        b.append("]");
    }
// ...
```

The reason why you're seeing this in the log is very likely because of the intent has been dispatched by one of the apps or services, so the system can decide which apps to handle the intent with specific action and categories.

Comment: Does the log mean open a `VIEW` inside `BROWSER`?

Comment: It means an intent has been dispatched to view something and has a category of browsable to the system, and whichever of the app can support this intent will handle it.

Answer (score 1):

`act` stands for `Action` and `cat` stands for `Category`

More details are [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)